# Image won't show in custom format view of sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint

My images won't show!
Unsure why. There is a slot open in my list in the preview for the image but for some reason won't show, even though $Picture is the correct column name.

Any ideas for why?
The column isn't hidden, I have list entries that have pictures and some without. I'm really not sure why they don't show, I've been stuck on this for a while

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
    "hideSelection": true,
    "hideListHeader": true,
    "rowFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "align-items": "stretch",
        "padding": "8px",
        "margin-bottom": "16px",
        "max-width": "930px",
        "border-radius": "8px",
        "box-shadow": "4px 4px 8px darkgrey"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLighter"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "flex-grow": "1",
            "display": "flex",
            "flex-wrap": "wrap",
            "align-items": "stretch",
            "max-width": "310px"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "flex": "none"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "width": "100px",
                    "height": "100px",
                    "overflow": "hidden",
                    "border-radius": "50%",
                    "margin-right": "8px"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    {
                        "elmType": "img",
                        "attributes": {
                            "src": "=[$Picture]"
                        },
                        "style": {
                            "width": "10em",
                            "height": "10em",
                            "border-radius": "5em"
                        }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "flex-grow": "1",
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "column",
                "flex-wrap": "nowrap",
                "align-items": "stretch",
                "max-width": "200px"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "flex-grow": "1"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "txtContent": "[$Title]",
                      "style": {
                        "display": "block"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-l ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "txtContent": "[$JobTitle]",
                      "style": {
                        "display": "=if([$JobTitle] == '', 'none', 'block')"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-m ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "flex-grow": "1",
            "display": "flex",
            "flex-direction": "column",
            "max-width": "310px",
            "min-width": "155px"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "flex-grow": "1"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "span",
                  "style": {
                    "display": "block"
                  },
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontSize-m"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "Description:"
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "span",
                  "style": {
                    "display": "=if([$Description] == '', 'none', 'block')",
                    "padding-left": "8px"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "[$Description]",
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "ms-fontSize-m ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "span",
                  "style": {
                    "display": "=if([$Description] == '', 'block', 'none')",
                    "padding-left": "8px"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "No Description entered",
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "ms-fontSize-s ms-fontWeight-semilight ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your json, it's working fine(Modern view).

[image]

[image]